# Athena read-only request under the role with full access

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, aws-glue, amazon-athena

We have .Net Core app that is actively using aws services and therefore has almost all permissions. It interacts with Athena via aws .net sdk and running pre-defined queries mostly, but there is one place in it where user can run his own query against Athena database and there is a theoretical possibility that he can run some malicious request like Drop Database and it will get executed, since the app has full access.

So the question is if there is a way to send read-only request from the app that has full access so that any request other than Select will automatically fail?

In sdk, there is an option to specify workgroup for request, and my idea was to create readonly workgroup with readonly permissions and send user request under it, but the problem here is that there is no way to assign Glue permissions bound to Athena workgroup, and therefore Alter Table requests for example are being executed just fine because app has a full access to Glue.

Parsing request with regexes sounds too complicated because it's rather hard to anticipate all sql injections possibilities, it's actually a separate big complicated task of implementing parsing engine and I  have neither the time nor the wish to work on that.

Another idea was to create lambda just for this particular task, that solves the issue, but I don't like this solution, it's a really hacky and inconvenient way of doing this.

So I'm wondering if there is an adequate way of doing what I described? Thanks in advance.